# No Instances available in Eureka Server

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am not able to see my microservice in the list of INSTANCES in Eureka. Here is the application.properties file for:

Eureka Server:

```
server.port=8010
spring.application.name=discoveryservice
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultzone=http://localhost:8010/eureka/
```

Eureka Client:

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=myservice
eureka.client.service-url.defaultzone=http://localhost:8010/eureka/
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
```

I am able to see Eureka server dashboard. When I launch my microservice, I am not able to see any instances available in Eureka dashboard. In the console I am able to see that the service is registered and started successfully.

Service started and registered with Eureka:
[image]

Console for Eureka Server:
[image]

Dashboard which is showing up in this link (http://localhost:8010/) instead of (http://localhost:8010/eureka/). Why??
[image]

So, I have two questions here. Why am I getting eureka dashboard in this http://localhost:8010/ and not in this http://localhost:8010/eureka? Secondly, why my microservice is not showing up on the INSTANCES? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this video link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhvJg4tDrpw&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZSKAFG6aCDVDP86Qx4lNas&index=20

Additionally, you shoould once check the pom.xml and see if the corresponding jars are available in the "Maven dependencies". You might use the pom.xml in this link : https://github.com/koushikkothagal/spring-boot-microservices-workshop/blob/master/movie-info-service/pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

You have to set below properties to **true** in the Eureka client in order to register them in the Eureka server as Eureka clients

```
  eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
  eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

And the Eureka server opens in the port you defined in the eureka application properties.
It opens in http://localhost:8010/ looks fine.

But we have to set property as,
      eureka.client.service-url.defaultzone=http://localhost:8010/eureka/

Changing the client register property would fix all your problems :)